# Convert an array of floats into an image

Tags: java, image, resize, interpolation, bufferedimage

my goal is to take in an array of floats, make an image, resize the image, then read out an array of floats from the resized image.

The data I'm feeding into the image itself doesn't correspond to a true graphic, but I'm trying to find a work-around for interpolating data when resizing a float array.

From the research I've done it seems like the steps involved are:

1. Create a WritableRaster object and feed it the float array
2. Send that WritableRaster object into a BufferedImage object
3. Resize the BufferedImage object (using bilinear interpolation)
4. Somehow get a float array from the BufferedImage

Help, tips, and example code would be greatly appreciated!!!  My brains fried today.

Comment: Which range do your floats have?

Comment: It's a 1D array of floats that can have any valid float value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you convert the floats to integers, you can create a `BufferedImage` out of them directly with using [`BufferedImage.setRGB(int, int, int, int, int[], int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB-int-int-int-int-int:A-int-int-)

Use [`BufferedImage.getScaledInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance-int-int-int-) to scale it, then use the corresponding getRGB() method to the above setRGB().